# Calculator App Not Running Correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to the wonderful world of progamming iphone apps, im following a series posted in the iTunes U from stanford university, the first app they get you to build is a calculator. now when I go to run the calculator i get the debug screen throwing a break at this line  `@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;` I have followed the tutorial to a T so I do not understand why I'm getting problems and the lecturer isnt.

```
//
//  CalculatorViewController.m
//  Calculator
//
//  Created by Jweezy on 3/12/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Jweezy. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorViewController()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;
@property(nonatomic, strong) CalculatorBrain *brain;
@end

@implementation CalculatorViewController

@synthesize display = _display;
@synthesize userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = _userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;
@synthesize brain = _brain;

- (CalculatorBrain *)brain
{
    if(!_brain) _brain= [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
    return _brain;
}

- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *digit = sender.currentTitle;
    if(self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber){
    self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
    } 
    else {
        self.display.text = digit;
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber= YES;
    }

}
- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    if(self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber)[self enterPressed];
    double result = [self.brain performOperation:sender.currentTitle];
    NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result];
    self.display.text = resultString;

}
- (IBAction)enterPressed {
    [self.brain  pushOperand:[self.display.text doubleValue]];
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = NO;
}

@end
```

The application crashes whenever a number is clicked and the following is displayed

```
Thread 1: breakpoint1.1 at the line @property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;
```

Comment: What have you tried? "Calculator App Not Running Correctly" is a statement, not a question...

Comment: What is the issue ? application crashing or something else ?

Comment: when I run the emulator, when I push a number it stops the program and the debug screen comes up with the error thread1: breakpoint 1.1(on the line i posted at the top), so far in the lecture series he hasnt gone through errors, so I am unsure what else to include.




yes the application crashes when a button is clicked

Comment: That looks like you have set a breakpoint. in xcode it's a blue arrow to the left of the source. Click the arrow and it will go away.

Comment: @emrys57 I have not created any breakpoints

Comment: Make sure that the property has a synthesize in the `.m` file - it looks like you're running on an older version of XCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it look like this?

[image: Image showing breakpoint]

That's a breakpoint. The message is the one you are getting. They are easy to create without noticing, by clicking where the blue arrow is. Click it and disable the breakpoint, or right-click it and delete the breakpoint.

Comment: yes thank you!!!! I didnt realize I had a breakpoint at the very start of my code, it was above the line with the error1!!

Comment: I love the easy ones :-) and thanks very much for the tick!